# SignalR SSL trust issue with reverse proxy(Nginx) for Android

Tags: nginx, signalr, signalr-hub

I am facing issue with SignalR using reverse proxy(Nginx) which has Certificates(Server, client and CA) and these certificates are self signed certificates, generated using OPENSSL.

Nginx Configuration is as below.

```
http 
{
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" 
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

     server {
                error_log "C:/Error/error1.log" debug;
                listen 8080;
                server_name localhost;

                location /MyService 
                {
                    root   html;
                    index  index.html index.htm;
                    proxy_pass http://XX.XX.XX.XX/MyService;
                }
                location / 
                {
                    root   html;
                    index  index.html index.htm;
                    proxy_pass http://XX.XX.XX.XX/MyService;
                }
                location /MyService/signalr/
                {
                    root   html;
                    index  index.html index.htm;
                    proxy_pass http://XX.XX.XX.XX/MyService/signalr/;
                }

            }

     server {
                error_log               "C:/Error/error1.log" debug;
                listen                  443 ssl;
                server_name             localhost;
                ssl_protocols           TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
                ssl_certificate         "C:\Certificates\server.crt";
                ssl_certificate_key     "C:\Certificates\server.key";
                ssl_client_certificate  "C:\Certificates\ca.crt";
                ssl_verify_client        on;

                location / 
                {
                    root   html;
                    index  index.html index.htm;                        
                    proxy_pass http://XX.XX.XX.XX/MyService;
                }
                location /MyService
                {
                    root   html;
                    index  index.html index.htm;                            
                    proxy_pass http://XX.XX.XX.XX/MyService;
                }
                location /MyService/signalr
                {
                    root   html;
                    index  index.html index.htm;
                    proxy_pass http://XX.XX.XX.XX/MyService/signalr;
                    proxy_http_version 1.1;
                    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                    proxy_set_header Host $host;
                    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                }
            }
}
```

I have an Android APP which enforce the user to select the client certificate(P12 certificate, which has CA and Client certificates packaged) for authentication through nginx and route it to server XX.XX.XX.XX. I have a logic which will successfully establishes the connection to the XX.XX.XX.XX server through Nginx. Authentication to server XX.XX.XX.XX through Nginx is successful.

I am facing issues with signalR in this scenario, wherein I am making a hubconnection to the server XX.XX.XX.XX like $"https://{hostname}:{port}/MyService/signalr/". When I try to start the hubconnection 
_hubConnection.Start().Wait(); **Getting error as One or more errors occurred. (The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.)** because of which my hub is not receiving any notfication from the server.

I have Referred the following links and tried the suggestions as suggested. Unfortunately I am not getting any breakthrough. Request your help on this.

https://forums.asp.net/t/2029050.aspx?SignalR+Unable+to+Authentication+with+Certificate

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/security/hub-authorization

[SignalR - Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44433067/signalr-could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-the-ssl-tls-secure-channel)

https://forums.asp.net/t/2095053.aspx?SignalR+and+reverse+proxy